# Ajax fetch data with html Tag in php as variable

Tags: php, ajax, fetch

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch_select_data_partner13101(val) { 

    $.ajax({ type: "post", 

        url: "data_empf_3.php", 
        data: { 

            get_empf_3:val, 

            get_von:"<?php echo '<div id="von2"></div>'; ?>" 
        },

        success: function (response) {

            document.getElementById("re").innerHTML=response; 
        }
    });
 }

</script>
```

That is my code. I got an error because I want to select on `data_empf_3.php` the date between date1 and date2. But if I use `get_von:'2017-04-01'` everthing is ok and I got the right values.

**My question:**

Why my code `get_von:"<?php echo '<div id="von2"></div>'; ?>"` is not working? I got only the date2(get_empf_3:val)thats the same value!

Comment: (1) Format your code to be human-readable.  (2) Show what client-side code is rendered by your server-side code.  (3) Define what you mean by "not working".  What *specifically* are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: Maybe escape the double quotes i.e. `\"von\"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer guys